# How do I create a HTML form that generates a JSON file containing all the data that was submitted to the HTML form ?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to create a HTML form where a user enters his name, address and gender. After the user enters that information and clicks submit a JSON file will be downloaded containing the information. Could someone please tell me how I create such form ?

Comment: I tried to use a bootstrap form but I don't know how to code the function in javascript.

Comment: @AshourIecho Show us what you have done so far. Then we'll help you.

Comment: If you can't code at all then I can't help you. And nobody will just do the work for you. You have to show some attempt at making it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use jQuery's `serialize()` function. Since you have used Bootstrap, there'll be jQuery for sure. So all you need to do is:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#myForm").submit(function () {
    var jsonOutput = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray());
    $("#genJSON").text(jsonOutput);
    $("#download").attr("href", 'data:application/executable;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(jsonOutput)).show();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
pre {font-family: 'Consolas', monospace; white-space: pre-wrap;}
form,
form ul,
form ul li,
form ul li label {display: block;}
form ul li {padding: 5px;}
form ul li label strong {display: inline-block; width: 100px;}
form ul li label input {padding: 3px;}
form ul li > input {margin-left: 105px; padding: 3px 10px; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<form action="" id="myForm">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>
        <strong>Username</strong>
        <input type="text" name="Username" />
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <strong>Password</strong>
        <input type="text" name="Password" />
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <strong>Full Name</strong>
        <input type="text" name="FullName" />
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <strong>Email</strong>
        <input type="text" name="Email" />
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="submit" value="Get JSON" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>

<pre id="genJSON"></pre>
<div>
  <a id="download" style="display: none;">Download Code</a>
</div>
```

**Update**

Using `data:` URI scheme, it is possible.

```
this.href = 'data:application/json;charset=utf-8,'
            + encodeURIComponent(genJSON.innerHTML);
```

Comment: That is really close to what I want to do but I want the JSON data to be downloaded into a JSON file.

Comment: @AshourIecho You **NEED** a server side script for that.

Comment: Can't the client side javascript generate the JSON data to a JSON file that will download after the user submits the form ?

Comment: @AshourIecho It **can** generate a JSON, but cannot generate files. That's the maximum power of JavaScript.

Comment: @AshourIecho I have found a solution for you. Are you with me?

Comment: Do I add the update code into the javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

I made following html form

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="block block-bordered">
        <div class="block-header bg-gray-lighter">
            <h3 class="block-title">Profile </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal push-10-t push-10" action="base_forms_premade.html" method="post"
                  onsubmit="return false;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label for="mega-firstname">Participant 1</label>
                                <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="mega-firstname"
                                       name="mega-firstname" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <label for="mega-bio">Age</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control input-lg" id="mega-bio" name="mega-bio" rows="22"
                                              placeholder="Age"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="form-group"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <label for="mega-skills">Subject</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="mega-skills" name="mega-skills" size="7" multiple>
                                    <option value="1">Sale</option>
                                    <option value="2">Real Estate</option>
                                    <option value="3">Employment</option>
                                    <option value="4">Loan</option>
                                    <option value="5">Renting</option>
                                    <option value="6">Finance</option>
                                    <option value="7">Construction</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label for="mega-age">Amount</label>
                                <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="mega-age" name="mega-age"
                                       placeholder="Enter bitcoin amount">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-slideup"
                                type="submit"><i class="fa  push-5-r"></i> Submit
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```